# How to pass data to symfony form class without using static

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've got form class and i have to pass args to it but i can't do that because i am using `createNamed` function which requires me to use namespace string.

**code**:

```
$form = $this->getFormFactory()->createNamed('form', FormType::class, $this->entity);
```

I can't pass this data into entity, because it is an arguments for creating the form fields rather than data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Controller method to pass the data?
What about using the constructor?